# How to import products with images with CSVI Free to Joomla VirtueMarkt?

Tags: joomla2.5, virtuemart

I have a question, how to import product images with CSVI Free to VirtueMarkt to Joomla?

The import without the images does well, but the images dosent work.

Here is my CSV file:

\"product_sku\",\"product_name\",\"file_url_thumb\",\"file_url\"
\"12312312345\",\"\",\"\",\"images/stories/virtuemart/product/7c62ddd3752228f2f48cb02850f97309.jpg\"

Answer (score 0):

You can Read/Write Excel Sheet data using PHPExcel Library.
It have the facility to read the images from the Excel sheet , ie you don't need to place the image path like `images/stories/virtuemart/product/7c62ddd3752228f2f48cb02850f97309.jpg` simply place the image inside excel sheet and read these with PHPExcel,

A sample [image reader integration with PHPExcel](http://www.walkswithme.net/reading-images-from-excel-sheet-using-phpexcel) you can find here.

Right now I'm developing a component for VM to import and export product.
So hope its helps..